# Variable Div size. Position top right

Tags: css

I have a layout where 50 percent (left right not top bottom) of the screen is taken up by a map and the other 50 percent is taken by content.

I have 10 div's with text inside them of variable lengths and I want to position something on the top right of each of the divs. The text is dynamically generated so there's no way I can tell how large the div becomes.

```
<p id="contents">
  <div id="contentDiv">
  blah blah blah blah
  <div id="positionedthing">Thing I want positioned</div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentDiv">
  blah blah balh blah
  <div id="positionedthing">Thing I want positioned</div>
  </div>
</p>
```

The p#contents is display :inline if that has any effect. I've tried

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
```

but it positions relative to the entire page and not each individual div.

Comment: "The text is dynamically generated so there's no way I can tell how large the div becomes." -- yes you can: JavaScript.

Comment: So you are trying to position something inside the divs which are in <p id="contents>? Also you should consider using a different tag for p as block elements should not be placed inside inline elements.

Comment: And IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @TylerH - OP said his CSS has "The p#contents is display :inline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/49LXw/

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, i just float what you need to the right side, 
and added some display css.  but don't use id for multiple element use class instead. or it will break at some point.

```
.positionedthing {float:right;}
```

Comment: Hi, The map is on the other side so float right doesn't work i think :(

Comment: the float right, is inside the parent, so it should work. let me see if i can fix that fiddler

Answer (score 1):

If you position something absolute, you'll need to set it's parent to relative. One of the only ways you'll get your div content to respect the content of the positioned divs is by floating them.

Here's my best bet for what you want.
http://jsbin.com/beduyiku/6/

notice you need to use classes when you have multiple items. ID's are unique identifiers, so you can expect document.getElementById('id') to always return only one element.

Comment: The reason isn't unknown. A position other than static (the default value) will establish a new "containing block" for its descendants. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned
Normally you would use `relative` for such use cases because relative positioning does not remove the element from the normal flow.

Answer (score 1):

To use `position:absolute;` in order to position something absolute inside its parent, the easiest way is applying `position:relative;` to it.

But, first of all, you should rethink your markup. Most important: IDs should be unique. So your `contentDiv` and `positionedThing` should be classes, not IDs:

```
<p id="contents">
<div class="contentDiv">
blah blah blah blah
<div class="positionedthing">Thing I want positioned</div>
</div>
<div class="contentDiv">
blah blah balh blah
<div class="positionedthing">Thing I want positioned</div>
</div>
</p>
```

The CSS may look like the following:

```
.contentDiv {
    position:relative;
}

.positionedthing {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/3S6vR/)

Comment: you should float them instead so they dont hide their parents content, see my solution :)

Comment: I think that dependents on what he actually wants to stick to that position. I thought of something like an arrow containing the word "author" like in some wordpress comments. In this case I'd use my solution and a padding. In other cases - yes, your answer